# What is the utility of the attribute GeneratedCodeAttribute in C #?

Tags: c#, attributes, code-generation

I generated some of my C# code with an external tool. Each generated class has an attribute GeneratedCodeAttribute. Why is my generator creating this attribute?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This attribute was set because this code is generated by tool, not by human :) what is use of it you might ask? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute.aspx) tells us:

> The GeneratedCodeAttribute class can
>   be used by code analysis tools to
>   identify computer-generated code, and
>   to provide an analysis based on the
>   tool and the version of the tool that
>   generated the code.

Comment: NCover actually can be taught to take this attribute into account when you compute your unit test coverage.

Comment: yes and that fits into definition, NCover is "code analysis tools"

Comment: ok, but... does it also change how the marked classes behave? 
For instance, a SOAP client generated by wsdl.exe from the original .wsdl file works the same when generated using wsdl 2.0 or wsdl 4.8? 
I compared the generated sources and they are functionally the same, the only differences being just some "var"s instead of explicit types, and of course a different version in GeneratedCodeAttribute.. will that impact bindings or other mechanics? 
I guess not, but I'm curious about it ;)

Comment: @Luke I am not sure whether your question is about wsdl or GeneratedCodeAttribute? The attribute has no effect on the execution. You can generate some code, then scrub this 
 attribute from it and nothing will change in the runtime.

Comment: thanks @Andrey, my doubt was about the attribute: I didn't know if that value could drive code execution on different ways.. for instance, some WCF code could inspect it and decide to behave in one way or another depending on the version it was generated with, maybe for back-compatibility... common sense would say it shouldn't, but I wasn't sure...

Answer (score 6):

The first link is its documentation and the second link is a detailed description of what this is for, why code generators produce it, and how code analyzers consume it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute.aspx

and

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/2007/04/27/correct-usage-of-the-compilergeneratedattribute-and-the-generatedcodeattribute/

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is most probably used by the generator to find back the elements it created, in order to perform updates for example. Beware if you modify generated code : depending on the tool behaviour, you may loose your modifications on a further update.

Comment: i doubt because usually generated code and normal code are not mixed in same file.

Answer (score 1):

One potential use is that Some coverage tools can skip code based on specified attributes. You can tell NCover to ignore code with this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant text from Microsoft blog article [Correct usage of the CompilerGeneratedAttribute and the GeneratedCodeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/codeanalysis/correct-usage-of-the-compilergeneratedattribute-and-the-generatedcodeattribute), in case it eventually disappears from their site (which is common).

---

## Correct usage of the CompilerGeneratedAttribute and the GeneratedCodeAttribute

*04/27/2007*

Both Code Analysis, FxCop and Code Metrics make extensive use of CompilerGeneratedAttribute and GeneratedCodeAttribute to distinguish between user-written code and tool and compiler generated code.

The following describes this behavior:

**Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2005 and FxCop 1.35**

- Tool Generated. Raises warnings against nearly all tool generated code. Uses an algorithm to turn off particular rules against code marked with GeneratedCodeAttribute and generated by specific code generators.

**Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2008 and FxCop 1.36**

- Tool Generated. Does not raise warnings against code marked with the GeneratedCodeAttribute if Suppress results from generated code is turned on (the default).

**Code Metrics in Visual Studio 2008**

- Tool Generated. Does not display or generate metrics for code marked with the GeneratedCodeAttribute.

Unfortunately, there are many cases of incorrect usage of these attributes both internally and externally of Microsoft, and this blog post is an attempt to make things a little clearer in the correct application of these attributes.

...

**GeneratedCodeAttribute**

This attribute is for use by custom tools that generate code. It should only be applied to code that is re-generated over and over and should not be used by templates that the user is expected to modify. Nor should it be applied at the type level if the type being generated is a partial class. In this situation, it should be applied only against the individual members that are contained within the generated part of the type.

For example, the following shows the incorrect usage of this attribute (it is being applied at the type level to a partial class):

```
[GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0" )]
internal sealed partial class Settings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default
    {
        get { return defaultInstance; }
    }
    
    [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string MySetting
    {
        get { return ((string)(this["MySetting"])); }
        set { this["MySetting"] = value; }
    }

}
```

The following shows the correct usage of this attribute:

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0" )]
    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));
    
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0")]
    public static Settings Default
    {
    get { return defaultInstance; }
    }
    
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0")]
    [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string MySetting
    {
        get { return ((string)(this["MySetting"])); }
        set { this["MySetting"] = value; }
    }
}
```